# Replacing a containers content with css transition between with unkown height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I would like to replace the content of a modal popup dynamically, and it do a smooth transition between the old size and the new size.

I thought I may be able to do this using CSS transition, however I have been unsuccessful so far.

My setup is something similar to the JS fiddle here, where I have a container, and I swap out the inner content with different width and height.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lsf76eby/24/

html

```
<input type="button" value="press me" onclick="changeDiv()" />

<div id="container">
    <div id="a">
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
function changeDiv(){
    var b = $('<div id="b">');
    $('#container').empty().append(b);
}
```

css

```
#container{
  transition: 2s;
  height: auto;
}

#a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background:blue;
}

#b {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes in a fork of the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w1na6bsf/2/). You can read more about this from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

I added a new javascript function, added a css property, and reorganized the css a little

- You must define all the properties you will make subject to the transition using `transition-property`
- One significant change is that my javascript function (as adapted from MDN) switches classes on a single div rather than switching the div itself.

Hope this helps!

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="target" class="a">
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
//pretty much straight from the MDN doc...
function updateTransition() {
  var el = document.querySelector("div.a");

  if (el) {
    el.className = "b";
  } else {
    el = document.querySelector("div.b");
    el.className = "a";
  }

  return el;
}
```

css

```
#container{
  height: auto;
}
#target{
  transition: 2s;
  transition-property: width height background-color;
}

.a {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.b {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. The problem is that I don’t have a class which I am transitioning to - sorry I should have made this more clear. I just have a different size content of a div. in particular I will know the width but not the height. Do you know if there is a way to do this with a auto height container?

Comment: This doesn't involve a transition anymore, but there's an easy way to fit the content  -- just set a height in px with `min-height`, and `height: auto` http://jsfiddle.net/w1na6bsf/4/ -- Click the "add text" button I added a bunch of times to see what I mean. Apologies if I'm not correctly grasping your intent...

Comment: Sorry yes this is kinda how I have it at the moment, I just wanted it to grow or shrink in a nice transition, rather than just jumping to the new size if that makes sense. So if I go from a table with lots of rows to one with only a couple it would transition over say 1 second to the new smaller size.

Comment: Perhaps I will have to get the height of the new content and then set this on the div, then I should be able to use the transitions I’m thinking

Comment: Yeah, I think this means you can't do it purely with css transitions, there will need to be some javascript.

Comment: sorry, my fiddle is getting messy, but this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/w1na6bsf/5/ I set the transition on the container, and used js / jquery to read the height of the inner div, and apply it to the container's `height` property in css. Since it's a change to the css, it triggers the css transition. I reduced the duration since 2s seemed slow, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll give this a go tomorrow and let you know how I get on

Comment: Getting the height of the div and setting this has sorted my problem, thanks very much.